# Samsung GALAXY Tab 3 (SM-T210) KitKat upgrade issue

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung, samsung-galaxy-tab-3

I have Samsung GALAXY Tab 3 (SM-T210) and recently upgraded it to KitKat.

I just noticed now that I lost my Samsung account. It's not on my application list either. Is there anyway to reinstall it? I've done factory reset and it's still missing.

Comment: Search in Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

What is the app called?
As far as I understand I think you are looking for [Samsung Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.pcw).